# Size calculator formula

Tags: php, logic, formula

I am working on website where I have to calculate the sizes of dresses. I want to know how I can calculate the approximate size of a dress by using these values: Chest, Waist, height, weight, inseam, Hips, Neck, Length. Just formula (like height* neck etc.)

These values may be single like chest or more than one.
These values may be in MM or CM.

See the [link](http://www.citt.ca/files/CITT_size_chart.pdf) for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you linked to, there is no overlap between any of the individual measurements (ie Chest, Hip, Sleeve Length) within Men’s, Ladies or Youth. So all it takes is one of each (Men’s Chest, or Ladies Hip, or Youth’s Sleeve, etc). For values in cm firstly I’d suggest converting to mm (1 cm = 10 mm) then, given your link is in inches, divide mm by 25.4 to obtain a value in inches to look up. Eg:

```
Ladies Hip     100cm    =    1000 mm     or 39”     ie     M.
```

Comment: I know this rule for CM to MM or Inches but i want to know if there is any relation between the above values.Ok i got my idea that there is no specific rule for that.Thanks